Find $x(t)$ given magnitude and phase plots of Fourier transform $X(j \omega)$

edit: The left plot is Magnitude and goes from -3 Pi to 3 Pi on w axis. On the y axis goes from 0 to 9 Pi. The right plot goes from -3 Pi to 3 Pi on w axis and from -pi/2 to pi/2 in the y phase axis.
I'm given these plots and asked to find what $x(t)$ is in the time domain. I have been thinking of trying to infer some properties like differentiation and time displacement, but I just can't get to a proper answer, so I'm hoping someone can shed some light on the correct analysis.

It's hard to read the text on your figures, but it appears the magnitude of $X$ is given by
$$\left{\begin{array}{cc}
-3 \omega & -3 \pi<\omega<0 \
3 \omega & 0<\omega<3 \pi \
0 & |\omega|>3 \pi \
\end{array}\right.\tag{1}$$
and the phase of $X$ is given by
$$\left{\begin{array}{cc}
-\frac{\pi}{2} & \omega<0 \
\frac{\pi}{2} & 0<\omega \
\end{array}\right.\tag{2}.$$
Assuming this is correct, can you write a formula for $X(\omega)$?

Note the characteristics of $X(\omega)$ suggest that the inverse Fourier transform can be evaluated as the sum of two integrals where the first is an integral over $-3 \pi<\omega<0$ and the second is an integral over $0<\omega<3 \pi$.

I believe this lesson on magnitude and phase of Fourier transform will be useful to you, and in particular slide 5.

@StevenClark Thank you Steven! Definitely helps along with Danny's answer!

The resolution in the images is quite low and I can't read what it says exactly, but the amplitude seems linear with $\omega$.
Therefore We can use this representation :$$ X\left(j\omega\right)=\left|X\left(j\omega\right)\right|e^{j\phi\left(\omega\right)} $$ where $|X(j\omega)| $ is the amplitude and $e^{j\phi(\omega)}$ is the phase.
Therefore : $$ X\left(j\omega\right)=\begin{cases}
0 & \omega<-3\pi\\
-3\omega e^{\frac{-j\pi}{2}} & -3\pi<\omega<0\\
3\omega e^{\frac{j\pi}{2}} & 0<\omega<3\pi\\
0 & \omega>3\pi
\end{cases} $$
Let us observe the inverse Fourier transform : $$ x\left(t\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits _{-\infty}^{\infty}X\left(j\omega\right)e^{jt\omega}d\omega= $$
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits _{-3\pi}^{0}-3\omega e^{j\left(\frac{-\pi}{2}+t\omega\right)}d\omega+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits _{0}^{3\pi}3\omega e^{j\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+t\omega\right)}d\omega= $$
We can take the constants $e^{\frac{j\pi}{2}}$ outside and we are left with:
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{j\pi}{2}}\int\limits _{-3\pi}^{0}-3\omega e^{jt\omega}d\omega+\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{\frac{j\pi}{2}}\int\limits _{0}^{3\pi}3\omega e^{jt\omega}d\omega $$
recall that $e^{\pm\frac{j\pi}{2}}=\pm j $ using Euler's formula.
We are left with :
$$ x\left(t\right)=\frac{-j}{2\pi}\int\limits _{-3\pi}^{0}-3\omega e^{jt\omega}+\frac{i}{2\pi}\int\limits _{0}^{3\pi}3\omega e^{jt\omega}d\omega=\frac{3j}{2\pi}\left[\int\limits _{-3\pi}^{0}\omega e^{jt\omega}d\omega+\int\limits _{0}^{3\pi}\omega e^{jt\omega}d\omega\right]= $$
$$ \frac{3j}{2\pi}\frac{2j\left(\sin\left(3\pi t\right)-3\pi t\cos\left(3\pi t\right)\right)}{t^{2}}=\frac{3}{\pi t^2 }\left[3\pi t\left(\cos\left(3\pi t\right)\right)-\sin\left(3\pi t\right)\right] \tag{Using Integral Calculator} $$

When taking the constants outside the integral, it seems you've dropped the $j$ in the remaining integrand exponent ($e^{t \omega}$ should be $e^{j t \omega}$), and consequently your end result is wrong.

I believe the left-hand side of your final result is now correct, but you seem to have omitted the $t^2$ in the denominator on the right-hand side of your final result ($\frac{3}{\pi}$ should be $\frac{3}{\pi  t^2}$).
